# connecting to data feed from SSRS

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, rss

I need to do regular snapshots of a few reports that are being generated by SSRS. I've pleaded for backend access to the data, but I am not allowed to connect to the database.

I have never done anything with data feeds / RSS, and I was wondering how I can get started with C# to grab the report generated in SSRS?

There's an icon **export to data feed:**

[image]

How can I grab this data programmatically? Is there a way to utilize this export to data feed option?

Comment: Have you considered using the the SSRS web services to generate the report?

Comment: @SimonHalsey like i said, i do not have backend access

Comment: Ah I would've second @SimonHalsey's suggestion, perhaps you can update the question and explain what you mean exactly by "backend access"? (I thought it just meant you weren't allowed to run SQL queries)

Comment: quite. If you can open a report, then you can access the web service

Comment: @SimonHalsey awesome!! can you help me get started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the Reporting server using the web services.

This article shows how to render a report:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render%28SQL.105%29.aspx

This'll get you started on accessing the web service

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787%28SQL.105%29.aspx

The links above are for 2008 R2, but should work equally well for 2005 - 2012

Comment: thank you this is amazing information. how do i know the path for ASMX file? rs.Url = "http://myserver/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx"; ????

Comment: pretty much. put into your browser using the name of the report server and you should see the wsdl

Comment: im sorry, i was bringing an example from the link you provided. i am saying that in the SSRS reports i am looking at, i dont see an ASMX file

Comment: the URL is more like ......Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSales+Reports%2fPractice+Contact+Information

Comment: That's the path to the report path. ignore that. just use `http://<yourservergoeshere>/reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx`

Comment: thank, simon. so i am creating a winforms application and adding a service reference to this file?

Comment: i was able to connect to it!! thank you so much. now the challenging part of fetching the report....